# How to remove edge cases for string and number expressions

Tags: javascript

I'm building a rock, paper, scissors game and working on excluding edge cases.

The function is setPlayerMoves(), which is supposed to set previously undefined global variables for player moves and give them a 'value' between 1-99. how do I excluded edge cases like wrong move type (eg. 'rok') or wrong value (eg. 100).

Here is my incorrect code:

```
function setPlayerMoves(player, moveOneType, moveOneValue, moveTwoType, moveTwoValue, moveThreeType, moveThreeValue) {
    if (player === 'Player One' && (moveOneType && moveTwoType && moveThreeType === 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors') && (moveOneValue && moveTwoValue && moveThreeValue === (>= 1 && <= 99))) {
        playerOneMoveOneType = 'rock';
        playerOneMoveTwoType = 'paper';
        playerOneMoveThreeType = 'scissors';
        playerOneMoveOneValue = 11;
        playerOneMoveTwoValue = 33;
        playerOneMoveThreeValue = 55;
    } else if (player === 'Player Two') {
        playerTwoMoveOneType = 'rock';
        playerTwoMoveTwoType = 'paper';
        playerTwoMoveThreeType = 'scissors';
        playerTwoMoveOneValue = 11;
        playerTwoMoveTwoValue = 33;
        playerTwoMoveThreeValue = 55;
    }
}
```

Comment: "which is supposed to set previously undefined global variables" - I strongly recommend against setting any global variables! A key tenet of the current JavaScript developer ecosystem is eliminating uses of global variables (and in software-engineering in general: **mutable static state is a bad thing**(TM)).

Comment: Outright invalid values are not "edge cases" because they don't sit along any conceptual "edge" of a domain of acceptable values: on the contrary, they're very much _outside_ the domain. The correct term is "invalid case".

Comment: Your JavaScript code invalid as-is, for example `moveThreeValue === (>= 1 && <= 99)` will give you a syntax error because `>=` is a binary operator which in your code has no left-hand operand.

Comment: Thanks, this is a project that requires global variables - I don't really have a choice, but thanks for the comment.

Yes, I know it's invalid. VScode is quite good at telling me this :) How do i make it valid?

Comment: When doing `moveThreeValue === (>= 1 && <= 99)` I suppose you wanted to do `moveThreeValue >= 1 && moveThreeValue <= 99`

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

Code for checking edge cases are wrong.

```
(player === 'Player One' && (moveOneType && moveTwoType && moveThreeType === 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors') && (moveOneValue && moveTwoValue && moveThreeValue === (>= 1 && <= 99)))
```

Also you are checking the edge cases for only 'player one'

### Solution

Check the values seperately before assigning values and create a `valid` variable
`let valid  = false`

```
let states = ['rock','paper','scissors'];
if((states.indexOf(moveOneType) != -1) && (states.indexOf(moveTwoType) != -1) && (states.indexOf(moveThreeType) != -1)){
 // valid state
valid = true;
}else{
valid = false;
}
```

```
if((moveOneValue >=1 && moveOneValue <= 99) && (moveTwoValue >=1 && moveTwoValue <= 99) && (moveThreeValue >=1 && moveThreeValue <= 99)){
 //valid value
 valid = true;
}else{
valid = false
}
```

Then assign the values.

```
if ((player === 'Player One') && valid) {
        playerOneMoveOneType = moveOneType;
        playerOneMoveTwoType = moveTwoType;
        playerOneMoveThreeType = moveThreeType;
        playerOneMoveOneValue = moveOneValue;
        playerOneMoveTwoValue = moveTwoValue;
        playerOneMoveThreeValue = moveThreeValue;
    } else if ((player === 'Player Two') && valid) {
        playerTwoMoveOneType = moveOneType;
        playerTwoMoveTwoType = moveTwoType;
        playerTwoMoveThreeType = moveThreeType;
        playerTwoMoveOneValue = moveOneValue;
        playerTwoMoveTwoValue = moveTwoValue;
        playerTwoMoveThreeValue = moveThreeValue;
    }
```

Also if possible
Create an object each for player1 and player2 like below and use.

```
let player1 = {
  moveOneType:'rock'
  moveTwoType:'paper'
  moveThreeType:'scissors'
  moveOneValue: 23
  moveTwoValue: 33
  moveThreeValue: 98
}
```

Comment: Excellent suggestions!

Comment: Thanks, this is great. But I'm not yet familiar with arrays (sorry, very much a beginner). Is there a way to do it roughly the way I've attempted? Or without an array?

Comment: Don't be sorry. We too have passed through that stage. You can check seperately like how the value is being checked. But it will result in a long line of code. :). eg: `if((moveOneType == 'rock') || (moveOneType == 'scissors') || (moveOneType == 'paper'))`